# Silverlight : How to bind a result of loadoperation to LineSeries chart which contains few null values

Tags: wpf, silverlight, c#-4.0, silverlight-toolkit

I have bound a my chart to a result of load operation. The result returned by the load operation returns complex type with values for some of the object's properties is null.

So I am getting an error in my silver light application.

The code of my XAML is as follows:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <toolkit:Chart Name="historicalTotalChart" Title="Chart Title">
            <toolkit:LineSeries >

            </toolkit:LineSeries>
        </toolkit:Chart>
    </Grid>
```

Code of in my CS file is as follows:

```
LoadOperation<GetHistoricalTotalReport_Result> hisTotalsLoadOp =
                context.Load(context.GetHistoricalToalReportQuery(tableName, sD, startDate, endDate));

            LineSeries line = new LineSeries();
            line.ItemsSource = hisTotalsLoadOp.Entities;

            //line.DependentValuePath ="rep_date";
            //line.IndependentValuePath = "expr1";
            line.DependentValueBinding = new Binding("[rep_date]");
            line.IndependentValueBinding = new Binding("[expr1]");
            line.Title = "Historical Totals";
            historicalTotalChart.Series.Add(line);
```

Can any one say how can I over come this error?

rep_date, expr1 are the properties with in my complex type GetHistoricalTotalReport_Result. I am I binding to the properties correctly?

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Try to remove square brackets in the binding. But commented lines must work too. Also you already have the LineSeries element in the XAML code, but you create a new LineSeries object, which looks somehow incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My concerns is suppose when plotting the data if the Y values are null doesn't the application crash? I guess my application is crashing because of null values for Y axis values. How can I overcome this?

Comment: I've posted the answer, where I've shown that null values on the Y-axis will work, but on the X-axis won't. You must have confused the concepts Dependent/Independent value. The `rep_date` seems to be of the `DateTime` type and should be on the X axis (IndependentValue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 possible issues in your application:

1. Your bindings shouldn't contain square brackets, they are for arrays and dictionaries. Also I would rather use the properties `Dependent`/`IndependentValuePath`, you shouldn't comment them, they are completely correct.
2. The `DependentValuePath` property must be of a numerical data type, because it is situated on the Y-axis. In your example the `rep_date` property could be of the `double` type.
3. The `IndependentValuePath` is situated on the X-axis and could be of any type but the values can't contain nulls. Really, I have no idea where a null value can be displayed on the X-axis, it doesn't make sense.

Here is the example of the correct code which works fine:

```
LineSeries line = new LineSeries();
line.ItemsSource = new[]
{
    new ItemViewModel{expr1 = "Item1", rep_date = 25},
    new ItemViewModel{expr1 = "Item2", rep_date = null},
    new ItemViewModel{expr1 = "Item3", rep_date = 31},
    new ItemViewModel{expr1 = "Item4", rep_date = null},
};

line.DependentValuePath = "rep_date";
line.IndependentValuePath = "expr1";
line.Title = "Historical Totals";
historicalTotalChart.Series.Add(line);
```

The next code will not work:

```
line.ItemsSource = new[]
{
    new ItemViewModel{expr1 = null, rep_date = 25} //wrong, x-value can't be null
}
```

But you can filter your entities before displaying them:

```
line.ItemsSource = hisTotalsLoadOp.Entities.Where(e => e.expr1 != null).ToList();
```

Comment: @Vortex Thank you very much. What ever you have suggested has worked out for me. Much appreciated. Can I draw spline curve using SilverToolkit? I guess I cannot.

Comment: @coolcake If only I knew how the spline curve looks like. I suppose it is a some kind of a smooth line whereas the default line series have sharp edges. If so, you can do this. The LineSeries are based on the `Polyline` element and all that you have to do is to define a custom line which draws the spline curve from a collection of points.